# Matplotlib margins/padding when using limits

Tags: matplotlib, padding, margins

I'm trying to set xlimits and keep the margins. 
In a simplified code, the dataset contains 50 values. When plotting the whole data set, it is fine. However, I only want to plot values 20-40. The plot starts and ends without having any margins.

How do I plot values 20-40 but keep the margins?
Online I found to ways to play with the margin/padding

1) plt.tight_layout(**pad=1.08**, h_pad=None, w_pad=None, rect=None)

2) ax1.margins(0.05)

Both, however, do not seem to work when using xlimits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 200, 50)
y = np.random.random(len(x))

fig_1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4)) 
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_xlim(x[19], x[40])  

# ax1.plot(x[19:40], y[19:40]) 
# would create exactly the plot I want. But it is not the solution I am looking for. 
# I cannot change/slice the data. I want to change the figure.
```

[image]

Comment: `dx = 0.05*(x[40] - x[19]); ax1.set_xlim(x[19]-dx, x[40]+dx)` ?

Comment: The plot would start earlier and end later, but the datapoints would be included. I want to include margins (white spaces), no data points before and after the x[19], x[40]

Comment: The only way to have no datapoints shown would be to not plot them, i.e. `ax1.plot(x[19:40], y[19:40])`, which is the solution you already know about. You could then register a callback to limit changes and reset the data depending on the new limits after panning.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the reply! I thought there has to be a way to tell matplotlib to use xlim and just add margins without showing the the datapoints